# Interactive Login coming for child run during hyperparameter tuning (hyperdrive) in Azure ML Notebook

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a train.py script in Azure and it has the data cleaning, wrangling and classification part using XGBoost. Then I have created a ipynb file to do hyperparameter tuning by calling train.py script.

The child runs keep asking me to perform manual interactive login for every run. Please see the image.
I did the interactive login for many runs but still it will ask me everytime.

[image]

Here is the code in ipynb file:

```
subscription_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
resource_group = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
workspace_name = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
myenv = Environment(workspace=workspace, name="myenv")

from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
conda_dep = CondaDependencies()

conda_dep.add_pip_package("numpy")
conda_dep.add_pip_package("pandas")
conda_dep.add_pip_package("nltk")
conda_dep.add_pip_package("sklearn")
conda_dep.add_pip_package("xgboost")

myenv.python.conda_dependencies = conda_dep

experiment_name = 'experiments_xgboost_hyperparams'
experiment = Experiment(workspace, experiment_name)

from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget, AmlCompute
from azureml.core.compute_target import ComputeTargetException

compute_cluster_name = 'shan'

try:
    compute_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=workspace, name = compute_cluster_name)
    print('Found the compute cluster')

except ComputeTargetException:
    compute_config = AmlCompute.provisioning_configuration(vm_size="STANDARD_DS3_V2", max_nodes=4)
    compute_target = ComputeTarget.create(workspace, compute_cluster_name, compute_config)
    compute_target.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)

early_termination_policy = BanditPolicy(slack_factor=0.01)

from azureml.train.hyperdrive import RandomParameterSampling
from azureml.train.hyperdrive import uniform, choice
ps = RandomParameterSampling( {
        'learning_rate': uniform(0.1, 0.9),
        'max_depth': choice(range(3,8)),
        'n_estimators': choice(300, 400, 500, 600)
    }
)

primary_metric_name="accuracy",
primary_metric_goal=PrimaryMetricGoal.MAXIMIZE



 from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig
    script_run_config = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='.', script='train.py', compute_target=compute_target, environment=myenv)
    # script_run_config.run_config.target = compute_target
    
    # Create a HyperDriveConfig using the estimator, hyperparameter sampler, and policy.
    hyperdrive_config = HyperDriveConfig(run_config=script_run_config,
                                        hyperparameter_sampling=ps,
                                        policy=early_termination_policy,
                                        primary_metric_name="accuracy",
                                        primary_metric_goal=PrimaryMetricGoal.MAXIMIZE,
                                        max_total_runs=10,
                                        max_concurrent_runs=4)

hyperdrive = experiment.submit(config=hyperdrive_config)

RunDetails(hyperdrive).show()
hyperdrive.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

This just keeps asking me interactive login for every child run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement an authentication method to avoid having interactive authentication.

The issue comes from this line :

```py
workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
```

Azure ML SDK tries to access a `Workspace` only based on its name, the subscription id and the associated resource group. It does not know if you have access to it, this it why it asks you to authenticate through an URL.

I would suggest implementing an authentication through a service principal, you can find the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-setup-authentication#configure-a-service-principal).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will surely try this.